# Is it valid to to multiply an equation with general variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $y= x^2+x$.

Is it valid/legal to multiply
$(x^2+x)$ by $x/x$?
As $x$ can be $0$ too. So $0$/0 can't be expressed as 1... But on contrary side, $x$ can be $1, 2, -1,$ etc. any possible real number too and can be cancelled to $1$.
So what's the solution?

Answer (score 4):

In such situations, we usually divide the problem in two cases:

**Case 1**

If $x=0$, then work out using $x=0$.

**Case 2**

If $x\neq0$, then you can safely divide by $x$.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: But sir/ma'am the problem is that we don't know the value of x. As x can range (-infinity,+infinity)......

Comment: Yes, we don't know $x$. But, just see: there are two possibilities- either $x$ is zero or it is not.